# I'd like to read a column of a tab-delimited file, search for a matching entry in another file, then replace the term

Tags: python, csv

I have a job I'd like to automate and would love some help :)

I have a tab-delimited file containing three columns (and no headers). The first two columns contain identifiers, whilst the third contains number values. It looks a little like so:

```
ID1  ID2  0.123
ID3  ID4  0.456
ID5  ID6  0.789
```

So far, I'm reading the columns of this file using this piece of code:

```
with open(f) as tsv:
    for column in zip(*[line for line in csv.reader(tsv, delimiter="\t")]):
       for i in column:
          Change_Name(i)
```

Which is great. If I include a print statement it returns three tuples containing the entries of the three respective columns.

What I'd like to do next is to iterate over another file, finding the lines which match each `ID` entry, and replace the values in my original file with the 'name' field entry from the matching line. The third column needs to remain the same as it represents an interaction between the two IDs.

So far I have a function `Change_Name`, which takes one argument, opens another `csv` file, and iterates over it to find the line containing a match to the `ID`. Once it finds a match it prints the value of another field on that line. That functions looks a little like:

```
def Change_Name(ID):
        file_csv = csv.DictReader(open('file.csv'))
        for row in file_csv:
             if row['ID'] == ID:
                   print(row['Name'])
```

What I would like to achieve however is that the `Name` value is replaced into the same position as the ID used to find it. I've messed about with `str.replace`, however I've so far been able to produce a file which is structured the same way as the first, but with the `ID` replaced with `Name`.

I hope my question makes some sense, any help is hugely appreciated.

EDIT: I've been asked to show an example of my other file and what I would expect.

My other file looks a little like:

```
ID,  Name,  att1,  att2
ID1,  matt,  8,  abc
ID2,  jo,  17,  def
```

so if I was using a file like the one I showed above, I'd like my script to replace the `ID1` and `ID2` entries and replace them with 'matt' and 'jo', like so:

```
matt  jo  0.123
ID3  ID4  0.456
ID5  ID6  0.789
```

and so on...

Comment: Could you edit the question to include a sample from your other CSV file, and also the expected output you would get.

Comment: No problemo, I've added some clarificaiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you are trying to do. First it loads your second file in (I have assumed it is a comma separated csv as per your example). With each entry being stored in a dictionary. It then loads your main tab delimited csv file and attempts to replace the first two column entries with values from the `ids` dictionary. If an entry is not present, it uses the existing value for each:

```
import csv

ids = {}

with open('file 2.csv') as f_file2:
    csv_file2 = csv.reader(f_file2, skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(csv_file2)

    for cols in csv_file2:
        ids[cols[0]] = cols[1]

with open('file 1.csv', 'rb') as f_file1, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_file1 = csv.reader(f_file1, delimiter='\t')
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')

    for cols in csv_file1:
        csv_output.writerow([ids.get(cols[0], cols[0]), ids.get(cols[1], cols[1]), cols[2]])
```

Giving you `output.csv` containing:

```
matt    jo  0.123
ID3 ID4 0.456
ID5 ID6 0.789
```

Tested using Python 2.7.9